# Scramble Images- Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, swap

I have a 3x4 table of images that I want to be scrambled like a puzzle. There are a total of 12 separate gifs. Where I need help is, Using strictly javascript, how could I set this up so it randomly scrambles the images every time the page loads? So far, I have loaded all the images into an array like so:

Incomplete JS:

```
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'pic_01.gif';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'pic_02.gif';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'pic_03.gif';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'pic_04.gif';

etc... pic_05.gif...
```

My HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th> <img src="pic_01.gif" onclick="imageSwap()" alt="" border= height=100           width=100></img> </th>
    <td> <img src="pic_02.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_03.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <img src="pic_04.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_05.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_06.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <img src="pic_07.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_08.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_09.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <img src="pic_10.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_11.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
    <td> <img src="pic_12.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I would ultimately like to do is be able to have a user click one 'randomized' image and swap it with another 'randomized' image, to solve the puzzle.  Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to add a class (let's say `random`) to each `img` element:

```
<img src="pic_10.gif" class="random" alt="" height=100 width=100 />
```

Then we can get all the images with a simple `querySelectorAll`:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.random');
```

Randomize the array of `src`s:

```
var srcs = ['pic_01.gif', 'pic_01.gif', etc, etc];
srcs = srcs.sort(function() { return Math.random() > 0.5; });
```

Then iterate over the images, applying the new src to each:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
  images[i].src = srcs[i];
}
```

The full function being:

```
var imageSwap = function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.random');

  var srcs = ['pic_01.gif', 'pic_01.gif', etc, etc];
  srcs = srcs.sort(function() { return Math.random() > 0.5; });


  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    images[i].src = srcs[i];
  }
};
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6p6uG/)

Comment: Okay, I see what you did.  I'm still familiarizing myself with available methods in javascript, as I'm very new to it. How would I go about allowing the user to click and 'swap' with another image. For example, in my webpage, there is a puzzle, so after the puzzle has been randomized, the user could try to 'solve' the puzzle.

Comment: @swam that's a separate question.  I'd try it out on your own, and then ask a new question if you can't get the hang of it.  For now, don't forget to upvote and accept by clicking the check mark!